# How to check if the required attribute is set on a field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, required

I have a simple form that has some required fields in it.

```
<form name="form" method="post">
<pre>
<label>     Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" required>
<label>  Address: </label><input type="text" name="add" required>
<label>Telephone: </label><input type="text" name="tel">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form"> 
</pre>
</form>
```

I know you can set the required attribute using `document.forms['form']['name'].required = false`. But is there a way where you can just check if the required attribute is set or not? I tried using `getattribute()` but it just returns blank. I also tried using the code below, but it always executes the statement, even if the required attribute isn't set (e.g. on the telephone field).

```
 if( document.forms['form']['name'].required = true)
     label.innerHTML += " (required)"
```

Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

**Update:** Both setting the if statement to `==` instead of `=` and using hasAttribute work, thanks.

Comment: Make that an `==` in the `if()`. Or actually do something like `alert("value: " + document.forms['form']['name'].required);` and check for that value.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but if `getAttribute` returns either `null` or `""`, that means the attribute doesn't exist on that element, which is what you want to know.

Comment: Your need to make it a check, not assignment. It should work, ie checking for `if(document.forms['form']['name'].required)` . Here you are assigning instead of testing because of `=` which will always return true.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this :

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

if(elem.hasAttribute('required')){
//do your stuff
}
```